# Different color for item label in pie chart jasper

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

i tried to make pie chart with jasper report... I already write the customizer class for the chart...Anyone can give me suggestion about how to make item label color same with series color?

```
PiePlot piePlot = (PiePlot)chart.getPlot();
PieDataset pieDataset = piePlot.getDataset();
piePlot.setOutlineVisible(false);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);              
piePlot.setLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 7));                              piePlot.setShadowPaint(null);        
piePlot.setLabelOutlinePaint(null);
piePlot.setLabelShadowPaint(null);
piePlot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);      
piePlot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
```

[image]

I add picture...In picture, "0.07%, 6.18%, 93.74%" have black color...Can we change that color with series color? So "93.74%" have brown color, "6.18%" have magenta color...

Thanks

Comment: As you may know, jasper report uses jfreechart  (I have edit tag), and pointed to a question with answer.

Comment: I visit your link..there only say about how to change section color of pie chart...

Comment: Thanks for feedback and update of post, I have removed my duplicated vote, and will see if I can help you out...

Comment: There is no simple way (you can only set all labels with a different color), if you wan't different colors for each label, you need to override the drawLeftLabels() and drawRightLabels() methods in the PiePlot

Comment: I try to change labelBox.setBackgroundPaint(this.labelBackgroundPaint) with labelBox.setBackgroundPaint(lookupSectionPaint(keys.getKey(i))); on  method drawlLeftLabels and drawRightLabel...But it just change the label background...Is that really no way to change label color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution based on @PetterFriberg suggestion...

in `PiePlot` method `drawLeftLabels` and `drawRigtLabels` change

```
TextBlock block = TextUtilities.createTextBlock(label,
                        this.labelFont, this.labelPaint, maxLabelWidth,
                        new G2TextMeasurer(g2));
```

to

```
TextBlock block = TextUtilities.createTextBlock(label,
                        this.labelFont, lookupSectionPaint(leftKeys.getKey(i)), maxLabelWidth,
                        new G2TextMeasurer(g2));
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Great work!, edit to remove your unnecessary comment related to if the output is nice or not.... what counts is that it works!